# How to pass argument to Outlook.exe while running it without using power shell or other application using C++, MFC/MAPI?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, outlook-addin

I have my plugin written in MAPI C++ for outlook.

There is one requirement wherein if user does GAL delete, I want to clear the cache of outlook for which there is a switch **/CleanAutoCompleteCache** which will clear the whole AutoComplete list of outlook.

Now I know that I can do it by any power shell script or something but I want to do it from my code only. i.e the code from which outlook gets restarted automatically.
**OR**

Is there a way to pass this /CleanAutoCompleteCache switch while user opens outlook by double clicking the icon or Outlook.exe file?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify command line arguments when your application starts a new process, for example, to start an external application you could use the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
system("cmd.exe")
```

The second argument allows specifying parameters.

However, you need to close Outlook before launching a new instance and applying  the command line argument for clearing the autocomplete list. For that reason, you can develop an external application which can launch Outlook with a specified command line, but that application should be scheduled from your add-in to run and when the `outlook.exe` process doesn't exist. So, in your VSTO add-in you schedule the external application (or just run it and wait until Outlook goes out from the list of running applications) and close Outlook (see the [Quit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.quit(method)) method of the `Application` class).

Comment: Thank you so much @Eugene Astafiev. I perfectly understood your what you said. In fact I was thinking about that only like we can have external app which can run the outlook.exe with required command line parameter but the problem is, we don't want to do that. I want to supply the required parameter/switch to outlook.exe when user starts outlook. Is there a way to do it? Any idea if we can achieve it?

Comment: You can create a shortcut with required command line arguments and run it.

Comment: That is absolutely right, but here, our application is not getting run by our code. It's user who will run the outlook. so chances are that user will not use our shortcut he may run it by double clicking icon, or may run it by going to program files or may run it from RUN dialog. So in these scenario how to achieve passing of parameter?

Comment: You can restart Outlook on your own when required. There is no way to use a command line parameter by default. A user should use a link file or pass the argument explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Astafiev